# touchesBegan not functioning on programmatically created view and imageview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am programmatically creating a view and a imageview while in viewControllerA for an another viewControllerB before I then goto viewControllerB. I have to do this, as I am using an image from the imagePickerController. However by doing this, touchesBegan does not function in viewControllerB

I have set UserInteractionEnabled to true/yes in both the attributes inspector of the xib and programmatically everywhere!

My xib is just a blank canvas, with one View. I have tried different settings with the connections inspector, but still no luck.

Here is my code.

**viewControllerA.m**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];

    image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    SSViewController *psView = [[SSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SSViewController" bundle:nil];
    psView.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    [psView.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [picker pushViewController:psView animated:YES];

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 280);
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [psView.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [psView.view addSubview:imageView];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:psView action:@selector(endPS:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(140.0, 330.0, 80.0, 25.0);
    [psView.view addSubview:button];
}
```

**viewControllerB.h (SSViewController.h)**

```
@interface SSViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    IBOutlet UIView *view;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIImageView    *imageView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIImage        *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView        *view;

- (IBAction)endPS:(id)sender;
@end
```

**viewControllerB.m (SSViewController.m)**

```
@implementation SSViewController

@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize image;
@synthesize view;

:
:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

:
: 

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan");

:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a number of things wrong:

1. Don't push a view controller on to the `UIImagePickerController`. If you've presented it modally, which I hope you have, you need to dismiss it (in viewControllerA) and push your new view controller (viewControllerB) onto your own navigation controller. The fact that you're pushing onto this highly customised navigation controller is most likely why `touchesBegan` is not being called.
2. Why are you manually creating the view for viewControllerB? If you're loading it from a XIB file, it will have a perfectly good view ready for you. And don't define the `view` property in viewControllerB.h, it's already defined in UIViewController.h.
3. Don't forget to call `[super viewDidLoad]` in viewControllerB.m. This is a classic mistake that will cause you many headaches.

EDIT:

What I would personally have done is added a method on viewControllerB as such:

**viewControllerB.h**

```
@interface SSViewController : UIViewController
{
   - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image;
}
@end
```

**viewControllerB.m**

```
@implementation SSViewController
{
   - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
   {
      // In case the image view already exists, remove it first.
      [_imageView removeFromSuperview];
      _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
      _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 280);
      [self.view addSubview:_imageView];
   }
}
@end
```

This way, in viewControllerA.m you can just create viewControllerB.m and call this `setImage:` method to let viewControllerB do all the work.

Comment: Thanks Guy...how do I then get the image onto viewControllerB, the only way I could work out how was by doing what I am doing. The whole purpose of my code, is to use the image (image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];) by displaying it in a new ViewController.

Comment: Thanks Guy!...I've now got it working using one of your suggestions. I stopped synthesizing the view and imageview. And it now works! I will also look into the method you have suggested above.